# Disable first letter capitalization in android webview (html textarea)

Tags: android, android-webview, android-softkeyboard

[image]

Hi! I'm developing a webview app for android but I'm stuck on a very big issue. As you can see from the picture above, the keyboard is different between the single line text-field and the textarea. It is very important for this app NOT to auto capitalize the first letter of the textarea, but also I must give the possibility to the user to use capital letters if needed.

The html code is very simple:

```
<input type="text" />
<textarea></textarea>
```

iOS solved this problem through these html attributes for the textarea:

```
autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"
```

This solution is not working for android webview. I sought everywhere but didn't find any solution. Is it possible to use the small keyboard even for the textarea via html/javascript/android?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
<input autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
   <input type="text" name="txt1" style="text-transform: lowercase;">
   <textarea   name="txt1" style="text-transform: lowercase;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

autocapitalize="off" works as of 2015 on Android. I could not find anything about autocorrect. See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/autocapitalize